# Regex: How can I repeat an expression, including the replacement capturing groups?

Tags: regex

I am using Den4b Renamer to rename files, and I have the following expression:

`([A-Z])([a-z]+)([A-Z])`

And replacement as such:

`$1$2 $3`

This effectively separates camelcase. I.E:

`230 VuduCumuloNimbo public.ens` becomes: `230 Vudu CumuloNimbo public.ens`

`DreamDroneFinale.ens` becomes: `Dream DroneFinale.ens`

But the pattern terminates after the first replacement. Right now I am just duplicating the rule three times to separate the next two camelcase pairs. Is there a way I can modify my expression so I don't have to duplicate it to get my desired output?

I want `230 VuduCumuloNimbo public.ens` to become `230 Vudu Cumulo Nimbo public.ens`

and `DreamDroneFinale.ens` to become `Dream Drone Finale.ens`.

How do I structure my expression to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does `Den4b Renamer` support replacing on regex lookarounds?

Comment: How about [`([a-z])([A-Z])` -> `$1 $2`](https://regex101.com/r/Lw4Bxk/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Den4b Renamer support regex lookarounds (in both directions), we can try the following find and replace:

```
Find:    /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/gm
Replace: (single space)
```

### Demo

This regex pattern matches any point in the input string for which:

- `(?<=[a-z])` a lowercase letter precedes AND
- `(?=[A-Z])` an uppercase letter follows

But note that this pattern itself only *asserts*, but does not *match* anything.  It is a zero width match, so when we replace with single space we effectively insert a space to separate the camel case components.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Renamer doesn't support lookarounds. The `?` symbols are throwing an "Unrecognized Modifier" error. When I remove the question marks the error goes away but the regex effectively does nothing.

Any other ideas?